# Number Theory: How to prove this statement (Lucas's theorem?)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Assume $1\le k \le p-1$ and $p$ is a prime number.
>
> Prove:
>
> a) ${p \choose k} \equiv 0$ (mod p)
>
> b) ${p-1 \choose k} \equiv (-1)^k $ (mod p)

Probably the statement can be proved using Lucas's theorem. But I'm not sure about the right way to use if so. So any hints how to prove the statement?

Comment: Use induction on k

Comment: Use first & http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsFormula.html for the second

Comment: The proof of Lucas's theorem that I have in mind depends of item a) so I would be a bit hesitant to use it here. Of course, you can also do this direction as an exercise

Answer (score 2):

For (a) the fundamental theorem of arithmetic shows that $p|p!$ and since $p\not | k!$ for $1\le k\le p-1$ $p|{p\choose k}$ for $k$ in that range.

For (b) Use

> $${n\choose k} = {n-1\choose k-1} + {n-1\choose k}$$

Then with $n=p$ we see that

> $${p-1\choose k-1}\equiv -{p-1\choose k}\mod p.$$

Since ${p-1\choose 1}\equiv -1\mod p$ the rest comes from induction.

Answer (score 2):

Lucas's theorem seems like overkill here. You'd also have to be careful, because a) is commonly used in the proof of Lucas's Theorem, so you'd need to have a proof of that theorem that doesn't use a).

For the first, ${p\choose k}=\frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}$ has a numerator divisible by $p$ and a denominator that isn't, so the ratio is divisible by $p$.

For the second, you know that ${p-1\choose k-1}+{p-1\choose k}={p\choose k}=0\pmod{p}$. Now just induct on $k$ and use the fact that ${p-1\choose 1}=-1\pmod{p}$

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{p-1}{k} = \frac{(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k)}{k!} \mod p$

All terms in numerator are multiples of $p$ except one which is $= (-1)^k k!$

and so $\binom{p-1}{k} \mod p = (-1)^k k!/k! = (-1)^k \mod p$